# type manager error while using clearfsimport

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

while copying the directories from local to VOB using clearfsimport, starting to get type manager errors as below.Is there any solution to handle this issue.

clearfsimport: Error: Unexpected value (2) returned by type manager "_html2"

clearfsimport: Error: Unexpected value (2) returned by type manager "_xml2"

Answer (score 1):

From [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21257409) (for `text`, not html),

> This error occurs because the source container associated with the version is missing or unavailable or because `cleartext` cannot be created successfully.

Try also, from [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146932), and as a test on one file using [`cleartool chtype`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_chtype.htm):

```
cleartool unco <filename>
cleartool chtype text_file <filename>
```

Then try again the `clearfsimport`, and see if that specific file still generates the same error.

Answer (score 0):

From the mgr_info.h file (it's in {CC install}\lib\mgrs):

```
 * MGR_FAILED_NO_PRED_CONT
 *                      Return value for create operation, indicating failure
 *                      as previous container does not exist.  Common case if
 *                      container was renamed before manager could open it.
```

If you have users who hit those files a LOT, and they are fairly large, you can have this message if someone else was doing a checkin, mkbranch, etc., at almost exactly the same time as the import was trying to do an equivalent operation.

This assumes that you are importing a new version for an existing file. If you CREATED the file and got this, then likely something erased the source container out from under you -- some AV's will do this if they hit a false positive.

If the file is busy, I would recommend changing it to a type that uses either one container/branch (anything based of binary_file_delta), or one container/version (file, compressed_file), as that will eliminate a lot of contention.